# Android device connected via "adb tcp" gets disconnected after some time

Tags: android, linux, tcp, adb, android-wifi

I have written a shell script to monitor Android device battery level(using adb) and charge the device if battery level goes below a threshold value. I start adb in tcp mode(port 5555) . My host machine and device both are connected to Wi-Fi network. For charging, I keep my device connected via USB power cutter to enable/disable power supply to the device.

Problem I am facing is, adb gets disconnected after some time. I have support in my script which keeps monitoring device connection status. If device gets disconnected, script again connects to the device(adb connect ) But sometimes device gets disconnected and it does not ping also.That time my script fails.

I have kept "Keep Wi-Fi on during sleep" to "Always" in my device's Advanced Wi-Fi settings.

Is this issue related to my network or do I need to change some setting in Android device which I am not aware of?